# CSS/Firefox - How can I get table cell borders to show up when printing more than one page?

Tags: css, firefox

I have an html document in which I am testing printing a table that spans a couple of pages when printed.  Unfortunately, in Firefox, the cells lose their border.

Here is my html with dummy data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head lang="en">

        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            table{
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            td,th{
                border:1px solid black !important;              
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <body>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Editor</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>ISBN</th>
                    <th>Revision</th>
                    <th>Reviewer Score</th>
                    <th>Last Edited By</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                ......
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It oddly works in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.
I realize that this was asked elsewhere, but sadly nothing seems to work.

On this page:

[html/css: table borders appearing on screen but not in printout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469693/html-css-table-borders-appearing-on-screen-but-not-in-printout)

I tried a solution found in the comments using @media.

However, this doesn't work as it seems to break the css.  Maybe I'm inserting this wrong?

```
    <head>
        <style>
            @media.print{
                table{
                    border-collapse:collapse;
                }
                td,th{
                    border:1px solid black !important;              
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

I actually found a possible solution on another question asked on Stackoverflow:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/how-to-prevent-table-borders-from-disappearing-while-printing

However, the top border on the headers is lost on the second and following pages.  The spacing is also a bit odd and I still have to add padding to the cells.

Is there an approach that will handle printing the table with the css applied that will work across IE, Chrome, and Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a solution, but if you don't really need `border-collapse: collapse`, here's a workaround. Draw the borders that you need to draw explicitly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-spacing:0;
            }
            td, th {
                border-right:1px solid black;
                border-bottom:1px solid black;
            }
            thead th {
              border-top:1px solid black;
            }
            th:first-child, td:first-child {
              border-left:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Editor</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>ISBN</th>
                    <th>Revision</th>
                    <th>Reviewer Score</th>
                    <th>Last Edited By</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Never mind the length of the code, that's just the rows pasted in until I was sure I had over a page.)

Comment: Thank you!  I tested this on Chrome and Internet Explorer as well and it works well.  I also added padding and other styling and it doesn't break.
I was making a print view template and this was unfortunately frustrating.  Thank you again.  I really appreciate it.