# Table missing Border(s) after auto pagebreak, using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, border, dynamic-tables

I have a table that has 13 columns with some merged. The header and footer is static and the tbody is dynamic produced by an echo of a variable from a php page.

All is well including the borders except when I try to print them, either PDF or sent to the printer itself. the print out is good on the first page but after the page break all the table borders are missing, the layouts etc are good.

I have found a temporary solution but is somehow of a cheat. all i did was to set the border-collapse to separate and cell spacing to 0. if you look at the table borders are there but the other half of the collapse border is still missing, I have thinker with the pagebreak-after, before and inside with no avail. when table border is set to collapse the border is completely gone after the page break.

Comment: "i have found some question related on my question" - what question? Also provide a code snippet to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: oh i mean this question. code snippet took ages  my internet is slow so i canceled it out. thats i tried to explain it elaborately. if you read it all im sure you'll understand what im saying .

Comment: Do you happen to be using firefox by any chance? If so, try switching to a different browser like chrome and see if the issue still arises. This won't take care of the situation completely, but at least you'll know if it's a browser-related issue, or something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: @Sheedo , as a matter of fact i was using firefox. i was so fixated on my coding that i did not pay attention on the browser. i am new to HTML JS and php. just last month i started porting my program to be incorporated with a website. as of now i can confirm that IE has no problem. i am still downloading CHrome. net really sucks here. TY

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: i have read a little about webkits or that -moz, do mozilla have a fix for this type of problem? i am targeting firefox to be used for the website. chrome has a tendency of going boated and resource hungry when prolonged usage . i am worried bcause i am building something data heavy. i cant seem to understand this web kit or moz. thanks anyway @Sheedo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS/Firefox - How can I get table cell borders to show up when printing more than one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306462/css-firefox-how-can-i-get-table-cell-borders-to-show-up-when-printing-more-tha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is known to have this issue. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306462/css-firefox-how-can-i-get-table-cell-borders-to-show-up-when-printing-more-tha) for a possible solution. It is suggesting that you explicitly draw your borders like so:

CSS:

```
table {
    border-spacing:0;
}
td, th {
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
thead th {
    border-top:1px solid black;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: -1; if a question is a duplicate, you should flag it as a duplicate rather than copying and pasting the solution from the other question.

Comment: @sheedo . Thanks, indeed FF needed explicit declarations of the dom. Thanks again for the reference.

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Comment: hi, it turnout to be a clipping bug from FF(firefox), the top, left or sometimes the bottom border was being clipped by the margin limit of the page. so i added <tr> before & after my tbody contents and set the border color to white so it would be hidden since its just going to be printed in a bond paper. the missing left border can be fixed be setting the tbody margin to auto. ... and since its my first post here and received a rejecting attitudes except -Sheedo , this message is then directed to him.